# PDO Not Working in php

Tags: php, pdo

Why this code returns false?

```
$db = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=apimanager;charset=utf8', 'root', '');      
$q = $db->prepare("select * from tbl_user where username=:u and password=:p");
$q->bindParam(':u',$username,\PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->bindParam(':p',$password,\PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt = $q->fetchAll();     

if(count($stmt)>0)
    return(true);
else
    return(false);
```

Comment: my username is:admin and password is:123 that acutaly exist in dbase

Comment: in order for prepared statements to work, you actually need to `->execute()` it. and you'll need to hash your password input if the saved record in that row is hashed also

Comment: Enable error mode right after your connection: `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: thanks ghost but i want select data from db and not insert update and... commands

Comment: @javadnaroogheh You still need to call `execute()` for your select statement, e.g. `$q->execute(); $stmt = $q->fetchAll();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to call `execute()` before you fetch your data, since you use prepared statements, like this:

```
$db = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=apimanager;charset=utf8', 'root', '');      
$q=$db->prepare("select * from tbl_user where username=:u and password=:p");
$q->bindParam(':u',$username,\PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->bindParam(':p',$password,\PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->execute();
  //^^^^^^^ See here
$stmt = $q->fetchAll();     

if($stmt)
 //^^^^^ no need for count, if something is in the array it's true otherwise false
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it this way...

```
$q=$db->query("select * from tbl_user where username=:u and password=:p");
$stmt = $q->fetchAll();
```

And there is an error in your first line... `/` is present before `PDO`

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=apimanager;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
```

Comment: Err. Where is `execute()` ? And global namespace doesn't makes any difference

Comment: thanks but if dont use preaper statment my code was not safe with sql injection..

Comment: @Rizier123 there is no need of execute when you use it this way... Try it you will get to know...

Comment: \ before pdo in line 1 is beacase i using name spaces... not need to delete it

Comment: @MoidMohd Err. sry, but you change the code now! And you even forgot to change everything! ...`username=:u and password=:p");` You can't bin params with query

Answer (score 0):

```
        $db = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=apimanager;charset=utf8', 'root', '');      
    $q=$db->prepare("select * from tbl_user where username=:u and password=:p");
    $q->bindParam(':u',$username,\PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindParam(':p',$password,\PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->execute();
    $stmt = $q->fetchAll();     
    //print_r($stmt);
    if(count($stmt)>0)
        return(true);
    else
        return(false);
```

thank you it solved by addin $q->execute();

Comment: Please don't add a "thank you" answer, just read this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28779232/pdo-not-workong-in-php#comment45836123_28779232